# Why AWS MQTT Broker is disconnected from client when retain is set to true while publishing?

Tags: mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am testing IOT implementation with AWS MQTT broker from my mqttx client app.
When i set **retain : false, everything works**, I am able to send and get messages but when the **retain is set to true it doesn't work** at all. Client is disconnected as soon as i publish message and i don't get any response back. I have tried adding option cleanSession : true but no luck.
My connection is a secured connection with all certificates being proper.

Comment: AWS IoT didn't used to support retained messages at all, but looking at the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html) that appears to have changed, Can you show the code you are using to send the message?

Comment: AWS of course supports retained messages. It was because of required policy. For support of retained messages a device (thing) should have retained policies attached to its group. [AWS DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/retained-message-policy-examples.html#retained-message-policy-examples-publish)
Not deleting this question for the reference

Comment: Please add a proper answer (not just a comment) and mark it as accepted that way it will show up higher in searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the IoT Policy attached to your thing supports:

```
iot:RetainPublish
```

Otherwise it won't work.